# How to search a large data structure and return the series of keys/arrays that gives a particular value?

Tags: perl

I have downloaded a complex JSON data structure from https://api.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/variation/v0/beta/refsnp/8127500

it is so large, I cannot search it easily.

I have tried Data::Search, but it does not return what I need.

How can I search a data structure/hash, e.g. the minimal working example,

```
my %d = (
    a => {
        b => 1
    }
);
```

search for the key `1` and return `{a}{b}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

sub walk { _walk(@_, []) }

sub _walk {
    my ($value, $s, $path) = (@_);
    my @r;
    if (ref $s) {
        if (ref [] eq ref $s) {
            for my $i (0 .. $#$s) {
                my $p = walk($value, $s->[$i], [@$path, $i]);
                push @r, @$p if $p;
            }
        } elsif (ref {} eq ref $s) {
            for my $k (keys %$s) {
                my $p = walk($value, $s->{$k}, [@$path, $k]);
                push @r, @$p if $p;
            }
        }
        return \@r

    } else {
        return [$path] if $s == $value;
    }
}

my %d = (a => {b => [0, 1, 2]},
         c => [0, 1, [{d => 2, e => 3}]]);

my $paths = walk(2, \%d, []);
say "@$_" for @$paths;
```